# Can't sync NSUserDefaults with apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, apple-watch

I need to pass 2 doubles to apple watch, for this purposes I set app groups in extension and main app, next:

main app:

```
groupDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.XXXXX"];
[groupDefaults setDouble:pitchDelta forKey:@"pitch_delta"];
[groupDefaults setDouble:rollDelta forKey:@"roll_delta"];
[groupDefaults synchronize];
```

extension:

```
groupDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.XXXXX"];
double pitchDelta = [groupDefaults doubleForKey:@"pitch_delta"];
double rollDelta = [groupDefaults doubleForKey:@"roll_delta"];
```

But the values are not passed. Did I forget something?

in main app code

```
[groupDefaults setDouble:pitchDelta forKey:@"pitch_delta"];
[groupDefaults setDouble:rollDelta forKey:@"roll_delta"];
[groupDefaults synchronize];
        NSLog(@"%f %f", [groupDefaults doubleForKey:@"pitch_delta"], [groupDefaults doubleForKey:@"roll_delta"]);
```

returns in log `-0.387812 -0.098052`

Comment: Are you certain the write then read are happening in the right order?

Comment: It's the way I share realtime data, so read/write is performing several times in second

Comment: The initial value for doubles I set In appdelegate of the main app

Comment: Is using `NSUserDefault`s the proper way to share data between a watch app and an iphone app?  If so, that's crap.

Comment: I write data 30 times per second in main app and read 30 times per second  (but with another timer) in extension. I'm not sure about order and possibility of simultaneously read/write. How can I synchronise it?

Comment: Well to answer my own question, this [web article](http://calvium.com/2015/04/9-tech-how-to-share-data-between-iphone-and-apple-watch-apps/) suggests that using `NSUserDefault`s is correct.  What a joke.

Comment: However Apple suggest using `openParentApplication:reply:`.  That looks like a much better option for data so frequently sent.  Also 30 times a seconds sounds like way too frequent.

Comment: Did you enable App Groups in Capabilities tab?

Comment: @BensonTommy yes both in app and extension

Comment: As @trojanfoe suggested, for this kind of frequent data, you should use `openParentApplication:reply:`. Now as far as your problem goes, Try deleting the apps entirely from device & watch and try again. I had the same problem testing this with the `Today` extension. Also check on the developer portal, that your App Id correctly has the `app groups` permission enabled, despite what you might see on `Xcode`

Comment: @Lefteris your suggestion helped me. It works very well now. If u would like I accept your answer - you can answer on this question. Thanks!

Comment: @ShurupuS Glad to see I helped. Added as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the apps entirely from device & watch and try again.

I had the same problem testing this with the `Today extension`.

Also check on the developer portal, that your App Id correctly has the app groups permission enabled, despite what you might see on Xcode

Answer (score 2):

If you use simulator,you can find whether those data were successfully persisted.

In my case the path is:

> /Users/benson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C4557E97-F6E4-48A9-B1C7-04441B3A0214/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/991C1FE1-6839-441E-A2F4-66834A683153/Library/Preferences/group.XXXXX.plist

Open group.XXXXX.plist file,find if those values exist or not.

Answer (score 2):

In the simulator, synchronizing NSUserDefaults does currently not always work. This is a well-known issue. I've spent quite some time searching for mistakes in my code and at the end it turned out that my code works perfectly on the actual Apple Watch.

However, I'm not sure if it is possible to write with such a high frequency. How do you ensure synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement shared container for having communication between main app and extension.

Check out the given link for watch kit tutorial :-

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW4